# GDAX Websocket API - Level 2 timestamp accuracy

Tags: coinbase-api, gdax-api

I'm currently using the level2 orderbook channel via the GDAX WebSocket API. Quite recently a "time" field started appearing on the l2update JSON messages and this doesn't appear to be documented on the API reference pages. Some questions:

- What does this time field represent and is it reliable enough to use? Is it message sending time from GDAX?
- If it is sending time, I am occassionally seeing latencies of up to two minutes - is this expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with the L2 api's right now and have the same question. I'm seeing a range of timestamps from 4000ms delayed to -300ms (in the future).

The negative number makes me feel that the time can't be trusted. I attempted connecting from 2 different datacenters and from home and I can replicate both sides of the problem.

Comment: In the future, posts such as this one would probably be better suited as a comment, since it does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @rickjerrity thanks. Don't get on here much. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this field reliably for a couple of months assuming it is the time the order was received, and it was typically coming out as a pretty consistent 0.05 second lag in relation to my system time; however, in the last few days, it's been increasing - over 1 second yesterday and 2.02 seconds right now. I note (https://status.gdax.com/) maintenance was carried out on May 9th, but it was fine for me after that for a few days.

To answer the question more directly, no 2 minute latencies are not expected. I would check your system time is correct. Quick google brings up https://time.is/.